# Use a single <label> for multiple checkboxes in a HTML form

Tags: html

I have a HTML form that looks like this

```html
<label for="Oranges">Oranges</label>
<label for="Pears">Pears</label>
<label for="Carrots">Carrots</label>
<label for="Apples">Apples</label>
<label for="Peas">Peas</label>
<label for="Oranges Pears Carrots Apples Peas">All Fruit</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="Oranges" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Pears" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Carrots" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Apples" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Peas" />
```

When the user clicks the label "All Fruit" I would like the checkboxes with the ids of `oranges`, `pears` and `apples` to all be checked.

I have tried to do this by adding multiple ids to the `for` attribute of the "All Fruits" `<label>` as similar logic allows multiple CSS declarations to be attributed to an element. This however does not seem to work.

Is there a vanilla HTML way of doing this without using javascript?

Comment: There is not a way to do this without javascript.

Comment: The [documentation for the `for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for) is pretty clear that it is for a single element.